# DynamoDB Map Create or Update (PHP)

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this:

I am currently setting key+values in a map in DynamoDB for unique objects.  The way I am doing this is as follows:

1. ConditionalUpdate - If `attribute_not_exists(MAP_NAME)` create new map populated by key+value. (This is in a try/catch on `ConditionalCheckFailedException`, return false if this exception occurred.)
2. If we didn't create the map (no exception), update map with key+value: `set MAP_NAME.KEY = :value`

I am opposed to using exceptions for logic flow, but I don't know if there is a different way to do a create or update on a map. Please let me know, or if I can make this question clearer in any way.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a different solution for this? I just ran into the same problem. Right now, the solution I'm considering is changing the attributes in the map to top-level attributes, but I would really rather keep the schema as is.

Answer (score 0):

it would be interesting to see your particular example, but did you try to make a "get" call to see if the item exists?

edit: It really depends on what you are trying to do, there might be tons of different solutions. DynamoDB is not as flexible in this as say MongoDB, and sometimes requires creative solutions to simple problems.

Comment: I do not.  Part of the reason I like using UpdateItem is because it sets the item if it doesn't exist.  Getting would definitely prevent the exception, perhaps at the expense of a call?  Do you typically use a get + set pattern for your updates?

Comment: Not really a fan of this solution, could cause a race condition.